# How to invoke AnimationExtender.onClick method from .CS?

Tags: .net, ajax, animationextender

I'm a ASP/JS newb and having difficultly trying to do something simple.  What I want to do is have an AnimationExtender fire and produce a window with text on it that I get from a database.

To do this i'm trying to envoke the onClick event from my selectedIndexChanged event handler in my DGV, but I can not find anything on how to fire the onClick event from .cs.  Here is my .aspx:

.style1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .flyOutDiv
        {
             display: none;
             position: absolute;
             width: 400px;
             height: 500px;
             z-index: 3;
             opacity: 0;
             filter:(progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0));
             font-size: 14px;
             border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;
             background-color: #FFFFFF;
             padding: 5px;
        }

```
    .flyOutDivCloseX
    {   
         background-color: #666666;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         text-align: center;
         font-weight: bold;
         text-decoration: none;
         border: outset thin #FFFFFF;
         padding: 5px; 
    }
</style>
```

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<table style ="width:1200px"; border="0";>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnColHelp" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClientClick="return false;" />

    <div id="moveMe" class="flyOutDiv">
      <div style="float:right;">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnCloseColHelp" runat="server" Text="X" OnClientClick="return false;" CssClass="flyOutDivCloseX"  />
      </div>
        <br />
             <p>
                <asp:label id="lbFlyByLabel" runat="server"  />
             </p>                       
       </div>


    <!--step 3 -->
<ajaxToolKit:AnimationExtender ID="AnimationExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnColHelp">
        <Animations>
            <OnClick>
                <Sequence>
                    <EnableAction Enabled="false"></EnableAction>

                    <StyleAction AnimationTarget="moveMe" Attribute="display" Value="block"/>
                    <Parallel AnimationTarget="moveMe" Duration=".5" Fps="30">
                        <Move Horizontal="350" Vertical="50"></Move>
                        <FadeIn Duration=".5"/>
                    </Parallel>
                    <Parallel AnimationTarget="moveMe" Duration=".5">
                         <Color PropertyKey="color" StartValue="#666666" EndValue="#FF0000" />
                        <Color PropertyKey="borderColor" StartValue="#666666" EndValue="#FF0000" />
                    </Parallel>
                </Sequence>
            </OnClick>
        </Animations>

    </ajaxToolKit:AnimationExtender>

    <ajaxToolKit:AnimationExtender ID="AnimationExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnCloseColHelp">

        <Animations>
            <OnClick>
                <Sequence AnimationTarget="moveMe">
                    <Parallel AnimationTarget="moveMe" Duration=".7" Fps="20">
                        <Move Horizontal="-350" Vertical="-50"></Move>
                        <Scale ScaleFactor="0.05" FontUnit="px" />
                        <Color PropertyKey="color" StartValue="#FF0000" EndValue="#666666" />
                        <Color PropertyKey="borderColor" StartValue="#FF0000" EndValue="#666666" />
                        <FadeOut />
                    </Parallel>
                    <StyleAction Attribute="display" Value="none"/>
                    <StyleAction Attribute="height" Value=""/>
                    <StyleAction Attribute="width" Value="400px"/>
                    <StyleAction Attribute="fontSize" Value="14px"/>
                    <EnableAction AnimationTarget="lnkBtnColHelp" Enabled="true" />
                </Sequence>
            </OnClick>
        </Animations>

    </ajaxToolKit:AnimationExtender>
```

Thanks in advance!

Chris